# Adding RadioButtons Dynamically To RadioGroup breaks Mutually Exclusive Selection

Tags: android, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

This is inside a custom view class  that extends RelativeLayout not inside an Activity or Fragment.
My `RadioGroup` exists in my `xml` and I'm trying to dynamically add `RadioButtons` to it. The only time I've seen it where the mutual exclusivity does not work, is if you do not add an id but I am here. What happens is when I tap a radio button more than 1 button is selected at a time. What am I missing here?

```
 for(String buttonName : mButtonNames){

         RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());

         radioButton.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId() );
         radioButton.setText(buttonName);

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         layoutParams.weight = 1;
         radioButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

         radioButton.setBackground(mRadioBckgrdDrawable);
         radioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);
         radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

         radioButton.setTextSize(mTextSize);
         radioButton.setTextColor(mTextColor);

         mRadioGroup.addView(radioButton);
 }
```

Background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/two_stage_toggle_button_on"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/two_stage_toggle_button_off"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I think you need to use RadioGroup's [addView(View, int, ViewGroup.LayoutParams)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)).

Comment: @TheWanderer : Nope tried that, same issue.

Comment: I think this might be a bug. What's your target API?

Comment: My Target version is 27

Comment: I also tried adding my RadioGroup dynamically, also same issue. Yeah it does seem like a bug

Comment: I think I've narrowed the issue --- when I do NOT set the background dynamically then the mutually exclusive selection works. I'll include my background drawable above

Comment: Try making an XML layout file that only contains a RadioButton. Set the attributes you want in XML then inflate it and assign an ID before adding it to your RadioGroup.

Comment: When I add from an inflated view the first radio button takes up the entire width of the screen

Comment: add the weight attribute. It won't suggest it for autocomplete because it's the root element, but it should still work.

Comment: Ah I got it ( making an XML layout file that only contains a RadioButton) you HAVE to to set the layout parameters dynamically including weight , after inflating the radio button --- yeah its a work around for now, thx @TheWanderer

Comment: you shouldn't need to. You can still define the weight attribute in XML even the editor doesn't suggest it.